# Allow only a cetain day of the month in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

My requirement is a little weird but something I can't do without.
I have a jquery datepicker and the user should be able to select any year, any month,  **BUT ONLY THE 21st DAY OF THE MONTH** . I tried

```
$( "#t_funin_teate_shikyu_change_dt" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var dt = date.getDate();
      return [dt == 21, ""];
    },
    language: "ja",
    orientation: "bottom auto",
    toggleActive: true,
    autoclose: true,
});
```

No luck.. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my rails app jQueryUI's `beforeShowDay` method didin't work and I still can't figure out why! what worked for me is down below

```
$( "#t_funin_teate_shikyu_change_dt" ).datepicker({
    format: "yyyy/mm/21",
    startView: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
    language: "ja",
    orientation: "bottom auto",
    toggleActive: true,
    autoclose: true,
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").datepicker(
        {
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        if (date.getDate() == 21 ) {
            return [true, ''];
        }
        return [false, ''];
        }
        }

    );
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HM83u/283/)**

**EDIT:**

In case if you do not want to see the dates other than 21 and hardcode it then you can try like this

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var day = 21;
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, day));
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/8761/)**

Comment: @TonyVincent:- I didnt get that. You mean you dont want to show the other dates except 21?

Comment: @TonyVincent:- If that is the case then you can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/8759/

Comment: All days from 1 to 30 should be displayed but all other days except 21st day should be disabled in the view

Comment: @TonyVincent:- I have added the demo for both the cases. In first demo all the days except 21 is disabled. In second, i have hardcoded the 21st day month so the user has to select only month and year.